# ggplot - control the number of graph per a page

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a question.
I want to plot 2by2 or 1by1 graphs per page instead of 15 graphs on one page.

this is my code :

```
plot =   combine_core1_and_2_and_average[]%>%
    ggplot()+
    geom_boxplot(aes(x =merge_data_core1.depth, y = average,col = geno_pheno,))+
    ggtitle(title_name)+
    theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
    xlab("Depth (cm)")+
    ylab(title_name)+
    facet_wrap(.~cluster)
```

[image]

Comment: the `ggforce::facet_grid_paginate` function does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much, is it possible to make graphs automatically instead of changing paper numbers.

Comment: Of course. But you need to know how many pages you need in the end. Then you can try a for loop or sapply, lapplay or map.